# Videojs-ima plugin with requirejs not including plugins on load

Tags: javascript, requirejs, video.js, vast, google-ima

I followed the example at [How can I use a videojs plugin when I also use RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163777/how-can-i-use-a-videojs-plugin-when-i-also-use-requirejs/36350488) and I have this prepared:

```
requirejs.config({
urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),

baseUrl: framework + '/',

//Framework paths
paths: {
    'framework': framework,
    'jquery': 'js/jquery.min',
    'videojs': 'js/video.min',
    'ads': 'js/videojs.ads.min',
    'ima': 'js/videojs.ima',
    'googleima': '//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3',
    'main': 'js/main',
    'config': 'js/config',
    'nearest': 'js/nearest.min',
},

shim: {
    'nearest': ['jquery'],
    'ads': {
        deps: ['videojs-in-global'],
    },
    'ima': {
        deps: ['ads']
    },
}
});

define("videojs-in-global",["videojs"], function(videojs) {
    window.videojs = videojs;
});
```

And when running a page I get en error:

> videojs.ima.js:1127 Uncaught TypeError: player.ads is not a function

I believe I should also include player or ads in some global scope but I have been working on it without any luck. Could you help me figure it out? I'm new to requireJs, still learning but it seems to do excellent work.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have initialized `player.ads` yourself *(not provided in question)* and IMA expect `player.ads` to be a function, what it is before initialization. So don't call `player.ads()` anywhere.

Therefore your implementation should look more or less like:

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video-js.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/videojs.ads.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/videojs.ima.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264" poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" autoplay controls>
            <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
            <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'/>
            <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.ogv" type='video/ogg'/>
        </video>
        <script data-main="app.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### app.js

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "videojs": "//vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.min",
        "ads": "./libs/videojs.ads",
        'ima': './libs/videojs.ima',
        'googleima': '//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3'
    },
    shim:{
        'ima': {
            deps: ['googleima','ads']
        },
        'ads': {
            deps: ['videojs-in-global']
        }
    }
});

define("videojs-in-global",["videojs"], function(videojs) {
    window.videojs = videojs;
});

requirejs(['ima'], function () {

    var player = videojs('content_video', {}, function(){

        /* solves problem, if vjs.ads isn't able to find Html5, like for me (properly version conflicts) */
        videojs.Html5 = videojs.getComponent('Html5');

        /* do not initialize ads, ima will do this */
        // player.ads();

        player.ima({
            id: 'content_video',
            adTagUrl: 'http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&' +
            'iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&' +
            'impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vmap1&unviewed_position_start=1&' +
            'cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpostpod%26deployment%3Dgmf-js&cmsid=496&' +
            'vid=short_onecue&correlator='
        });

        var contentPlayer =  document.getElementById('content_video_html5_api');
        if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
            navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) &&
            contentPlayer.hasAttribute('controls')) {
            contentPlayer.removeAttribute('controls');
        }

        var startEvent = 'click';
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
            navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
            navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
            startEvent = 'tap';
        }

        player.ima.initializeAdDisplayContainer();
        player.ima.requestAds();
        player.play();

    });

});
```

Please note, that I had issues with videojs.ads plugin. Probably some version conflicts. Would be glad, if someone could tell us, what's going wrong when vjs.Html5 is undefined within the plugin.

A quick and maybe dirty fix was to add this line:

```
videojs.Html5 = videojs.getComponent('Html5');
```

The configuration might not be perfect, as I'm relatively little familiar with this player and requirejs.

Have a nice day.